# find particular key in json and insert parent object to it using python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to insert parent object in the json but it inserts it on the top but I want to insert after particular key present in the json. I tried adding below code but it insert parent at the top (I understand since it is parent it will be inserted on the top but i want to insert before particular key in this case key is "pattern"  :

```
with open ("myfile.json", 'r') as f:
    myjson = json.load(f)

myjson = {'Main Parent': myjson}
```

Basically I want to insert "versions": before "pattern"

```
"versions":{
           "pattern": {
             "provider": "abc",
             "schema": "xyz" 
           },
           "baseline":{
              "version" : "dev"
           }
       }
```

Input json file

```
    {
          "target": {
             "Name": "abc",
             "Occupation": "xyz" 
           },
           "properties":{
              "env" : "dev"
           },
           "use_it": "xyz",
           "pattern": {
             "provider": "abc",
             "schema": "xyz" 
           },
           "baseline":{
              "version" : "dev"
           }   
    }
```

Expected output json file

Input json file

```
    {
          "target": {
             "Name": "abc",
             "Occupation": "xyz" 
           },
           "properties":{
              "env" : "dev"
           },
           "use_it": "xyz",
        "versions":{
           "pattern": {
             "provider": "abc",
             "schema": "xyz" 
           },
           "baseline":{
              "version" : "dev"
           }
       }   
    }
```

Comment: You want to *"wrap"* the dict entry. You want to create a new key `versions` which contains a dict with the key `pattern` with the value of the current key `pattern`, and then remove the key `pattern` from the top dict…

Comment: @deceze : Any example code please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
import json

with open ("myfile.json", 'r') as f:
    myjson = json.load(f)

# Add any top level keys you want to move into the `versions` key
versions_keys = [
    "pattern", "baseline"
]

myjson["versions"] = {}

for version_key in versions_keys:
    key = myjson.pop(version_key)
    myjson["versions"][version_key] = key

myjson = {'Main Parent': myjson}

print(json.dumps(myjson, indent=4))
```

The `pop` method deletes a key from a dict and returns its value.
We store that value and place it back under the new "versions" key.

Output:

```
{
    "Main Parent": {
        "target": {
            "Name": "abc",
            "Occupation": "xyz"
        },
        "properties": {
            "env": "dev"
        },
        "use_it": "xyz",
        "versions": {
            "pattern": {
                "provider": "abc",
                "schema": "xyz"
            },
            "baseline": {
                "version": "dev"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How the loop will look like , can you suggest if it is more than 2 keys ?

Comment: @Bokambo Sure :-) I just updated with a looped version

Comment: Amazing. Is there a way that I don't need to define versions_keys = [
    "pattern", "baseline"
] list and still able to get the keys  through loop ?

Comment: Unless you can programmatically tell which keys should be moved into the `versions` key, then I think you have to declare what keys you want to move somewhere.
If you have more information or constraints to work through, you can edit your question :-)

Answer (score 1):

yes,you can dynamically get the keys from the `versions` dictionary and insert them before the "pattern" key in your JSON!

check this out too:

```
import json

with open("myfile.json", "r") as f:
    myjson = json.load(f)

versions = {
    "pattern": {
        "provider": "abc",
        "schema": "xyz"
    },
    "baseline": {
        "version": "dev"
    }
}

index = list(myjson).index("pattern")

updated_json = {}

for i, (key, value) in enumerate(myjson.items()):
    if key == "pattern":
        updated_json["versions"] = versions
    updated_json[key] = value

with open("myfile.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(updated_json, f, indent=4)
```

as you see,the `versions` dictionary is defined with the desired key-value pairs,and during the iteration through the original `JSON`, when the `pattern` key is encountered, the `versions` dictionary is inserted before it!